# How to add extended library "android.supportv4.app" to your application?

Tags: android

I was searching around http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabsPager.html
But I couldn't find where is the source for FragmentActivity. I wonder how could I download this package so that I can add them to my application? Has anyone done it before could share me some information? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download it using the Android SDK Manager.Please refer to the link below.
[Downloading Compatibility Library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html#Downloading)

Answer (score 28):

Or you could just right click on your project in eclipse, select Android Tools, then click Add Compatibility Library.

Comment: Best Answer! This was by far the easiest method!

Answer (score 4):

Yeah I've done it.

- Create a `libs` directory for your project.
- Download the Support package.
- From the Support package copy the android-support-*.jar to your `libs` directory.
- When copied right click on the jar and choose 'Add to build path'.
- Done.

Comment: Where is the Support package? I do not see it in the Android SDK Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse -> Window -> Android SDK and AVD Manager -> Available Packages -> Download the compatibility library v4.

After download locate the android-support-v4.jar in the installed folder. Copy the jar to your project.